# POSIX shell semantic for exec and & (moving program to background)

Tags: shell, posix

I can't figure what happen on:

```
exec CMD &
```

especially what value for pid is:

```
echo $!
```

Answer (score 3):

With `exec CMD &`, the `&` takes effect first, so everything is run in background; then the command is evaluated, and `exec`'d, but that would have happened without the `exec`, so in fact that is the same as writing `CMD &` (but causes people to worry about why it was written thus, so it is bad style).

The value in `$!` should be the PID of the command that is executed in the background.